# unable to read file using apache fileupload in sturt 1.1

Tags: ajax, apache, html, file-upload, struct

I have made ajax request as follow

```
**function uploadFiles(url, files) {
alert("sss");
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) {
  alert("v"+file.name);
    formData.append("file", file);
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {alert("'ddd111000") };
  xhr.send(formData);  // multipart/form-data
}**
```

it send file to server but  when i tried to read request and file in it it in  using apache file uploading in strut 1.1. it return me empty List of FileItem object. please help me on this following is server side code that i write

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
                  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

              factory.setSizeThreshold(5000 * 1024);


              // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
              factory.setRepository(new File("G:\\Project\\"));

              // Create a new file upload handler
              ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);


              // maximum file size to be uploaded.
              upload.setSizeMax( 5000 * 1024 );




              // Set factory constraints

              // Create a new file upload handler
              //ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);


             // ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
             // upload.getItemIterator(request);
              List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

items list is empty . please give me code or idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files with plain AJAX.
There are workarounds in many JS libraries so it's better to use some JS library like Jquery.

Comment: but i got file in request, i obser it using firebug. file data in encoded form

Comment: Ok, if you use modern browser it will work, but the way file transmitted is a bit different. Struts 1.1 does not support this because it's older that feature you're trying to use. Please look in usual request parameter like request.getParameter("file"). (not in files).

Comment: using request object like this request.getParameter("file"), i got null